# how to use lucene for lemmatization and elimination of empty French words

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, lemmatization

i'm looking for how lemmatizate and eliminate empty words from documents written in French using lucene in java language i looked in the internet but i didn't find good tutoriels .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, all what you need is a FrenchAnalyzer like this:

```
IndexWriterConfig conf= new IndexWriterConfig (Version.LUCENE_45,new FrenchAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45,FrenchAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet()));
```

and for empty words we use : FrenchAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet() like i did in the previous code , and for the lemmatization it's already integrated in this analyzer and you can notice that when you look for the important words (by tf idf) .

Answer (score 0):

The term for "empty words" is [*stop words*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words).

Lucene provides the [FrenchAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/fr/FrenchAnalyzer.html) class, which comes with a default stop words list for the French language.

Just use that class as your analyzer.

Comment: thanx a lot , but it doesn't lemmatizate the words